# Check overlapping at offset - Phaser

Tags: javascript, physics, overlap, phaser-framework

I'm trying to write a function that checks arcade physics bodies overlapping at a certain offset. Here's my code:

```
function overlapAtOffsetSprite(object1, object2, offsetX, offsetY)
{

    if (typeof(object1.body) === "undefined" || typeof(object2.body) === "undefined"){
        return false;
    }

    var bounds1 = new Phaser.Rectangle(object1.position.x + object1.body.offset.x + offsetX,
                                       object1.position.y + object1.body.offset.y + offsetY,
                                       object1.body.width, object1.body.height);
    var bounds2 = new Phaser.Rectangle(object2.position.x + object2.body.offset.x, object2.position.y +
                                       object2.body.offset.y, object2.body.width, object2.body.height);
    return Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(bounds1, bounds2);

}

function overlapAtOffset(object1, object2, offsetX, offsetY)
{

    if (object1.name == "group")
    {
        object1.forEach(function(child)
        {
            if (overlapAtOffset(child, object2, offsetX, offsetY))
                return true;
        });
    }
    else if (object2.name == "group")
    {
        object2.forEach(function(child)
        {
            if (overlapAtOffset(object1, child, offsetX, offsetY))
                return true;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return overlapAtOffsetSprite(object1, object2, offsetX, offsetY);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Basically the function `overlapAtOffsetSprite` checks for overlapping between 2 sprites at an offset and the function `overlapAtOffset` checks for overlapping between a sprite and a group or between 2 groups by looping through each group's sprites and using `overlapAtOffsetSprite` on each sprite. The `overlapAtOffsetSprite` function seems to work fine when tested but something is wrong with `overlapAtOffset`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! After hours of staring at it I found the problem. I thought the `return` statement of the `forEach` function was the `overlapAtOffset`'s. So to fix this problem I used a `for` loop instead of the `forEach` function using the `group.children` array. I also edited the `overlapAtOffsetSprite` to count for the anchor of the sprite. Here's the code for anyone interested:

```
function overlapAtOffsetSprite(object1, object2, offsetX, offsetY)
{
    if (typeof(object1.body) === "undefined" || typeof(object2.body) === "undefined"){
        return false;
    }

    var bounds1 = new Phaser.Rectangle(object1.position.x + object1.body.offset.x -
                                       object1.anchor.x * object1.width/object1.scale.x +
                                       offsetX, object1.position.y + object1.body.offset.y -
                                       object1.anchor.y * object1.height/object1.scale.y +
                                       offsetY, object1.body.width, object1.body.height);
    var bounds2 = new Phaser.Rectangle(object2.position.x + object2.body.offset.x -
                                       object2.anchor.x * object2.width/object2.scale.x,
                                       object2.position.y + object2.body.offset.y -
                                       object2.anchor.y * object2.height/object1.scale.y,
                                       object2.body.width, object2.body.height);
    return Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(bounds1, bounds2);

}

function overlapAtOffset(object1, object2, offsetX, offsetY)
{

    if (object1.name == "group")
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < object1.children.length; i++)
        {
            if (overlapAtOffset(object1.children[i], object2, offsetX, offsetY))
                return true;
        }
    }
    else if (object2.name == "group")
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < object2.children.length; i++)
        {
            if (overlapAtOffset(object1, object2.children[i], offsetX, offsetY))
                return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return overlapAtOffsetSprite(object1, object2, offsetX, offsetY);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Apparently I'm talking to myself but, still, I know someone might find this useful in the future. A better way to check if the object is a group or not is to use: `object1.physicsType == Phaser.GROUP` instead of `object1.name == "group"`.